# Can Force.com Sites 301 Redirects handle open ended parameters?

Tags: community, force.com-sites, redirect

I am looking to map some of the Salesforce Chatter pages that automatically get surfaced in the Community and redirect them back to a Home page to prevent some of the standard pages from being accessible. It looks like I can set up a 301 redirect on the Community site like the following:

```
Source URL: /_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupListPage
Redirect Type: Permanent (301)
Target URL: /
```

However, if a smart user enters something like the following in the browser, it doesn't get caught:

```
/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupListPage?test=1
```

I was trying some different characters to see if I could create some sort of wildcard, but I didn't have much luck. Does Salesforce support more dynamic definitions for the Source URL?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  I've tried this, and it's going to read them exactly as written.

Custom pages can have client side (JavaScript) redirects, but probably not the default chatter pages.

Comment: A good thought. We can probably put some my dynamic javascript redirects in the Community Header HTML. Less appealing than configuring the 301 Redirects, but would get the job done.

Comment: You might consider a custom setting that resembles the SF redirect UI but feeds javascript on the page that supports wildcards.   Easier to manage that way.